# cron.yaml key not found "cron" upon deployment of simple hello world app

Tags: cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an elasticbeanstalk worker environement for my laravel application using the eb cli bit facing same issue as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61438390/running-cron-jobs-for-node-js-in-ebs-worker-environment-via-cron-yaml-file?newreg=39933435b7914046bacea5a64ad85b12) (apologies I was not able to upvote or comment).
I followed step by step [instructions](https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/laravel-aws-worker) to use the laravel-aws-dusterio package. Upon creating a new worker environment (eb create -t worker), I run into this deployment error:

2020-07-12 12:36:31    ERROR   [Instance: i-xxxxxxx] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].
2020-07-12 12:36:31    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-07-12 12:37:34    ERROR   Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

Upon checking the logs I found the following:

```
init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.1 (2020-03-30)
init: Failed of parsing file 'cron.yaml', because: key not found: "cron" (AWS::EB::SQSD::ScheduleParser::ScheduleFileError)
at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/lib/aws-sqsd/schedule_parser.rb:99:in `rescue in v1_parser'
...
```

caused by: key not found: "cron" (KeyError)

The cron.yaml file is place into the main/root folder of the project and is the following:

```html
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "schedule"
   url: "/worker/schedule"
   schedule: "* * * * *"
```

If I remove the cron.yaml the deployment is successful, however the worker will not receive the jobs posted from the sqs daemon. The web application is working correctly being able to queue jobs.
I can ssh into the ec2 instance but not sure what I could do to troubleshoot.

I am really struggling to fix this issue. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**
Trying to isolate the problem, I created a simple hello world application with a cron.yaml file as well.
This is the content of index.php

```html
index.php

<?php echo("hello world"); ?>
```

This is the content of cron.yaml

```html
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "schedule"
   url: "/worker/schedule"
   schedule: "* * * * *"
```

Step1: deploy application
eb create testworker-dev
the application is create successfully
eb create -t worker
the application is deployed but get same error as before parsing the cron.yaml

```html
init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.1 (2020-03-30)
2020-07-12T23:34:04Z init: Failed of parsing file 'cron.yaml', because: key not found: "cron" (AWS::EB::SQSD::ScheduleParser::ScheduleFileError)
    at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/lib/aws-sqsd/schedule_parser.rb:99:in `rescue in v1_parser'
    ...
caused by: key not found: "cron" (KeyError)
    at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/lib/aws-sqsd/schedule_parser.rb:82:in `fetch'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/lib/aws-sqsd/schedule_parser.rb:82:in `v1_parser'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/lib/aws-sqsd/schedule_parser.rb:59:in `load_schedule'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/lib/aws-sqsd/schedule_parser.rb:131:in `load_schedule'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/lib/aws-sqsd/cron.rb:26:in `initialize'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/lib/aws-sqsd/daemon.rb:47:in `new'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/lib/aws-sqsd/daemon.rb:47:in `initialize'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/bin/aws-sqsd:34:in `new'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/bin/aws-sqsd:34:in `start'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/bin/aws-sqsd:83:in `launch'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-sqsd-3.0.1/bin/aws-sqsd:111:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `load'
    from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd:23:in `<main>'
```

So the issue appear to be not in the application code itself. The aws-sqs is throwing an error when parsing the cron.yaml.

Comment: When you login to the instance, you can go to `/var/app` and look there for your app. You can inspect the `cron.yaml` if its correctly placed, has no funny characters or was not overwritten by something.

Comment: Hi Marcin,thanks for the suggestion. I ssh into the intance and cd to /app/var/current. the cron.yaml file is there and it looks fine.                                                              
`version: 1
cron:
 - name: "schedule"
   url: "/worker/schedule"
   schedule: "* * * * *"`

Comment: Maybe there are some invisible strange characters? Your `cron.yaml` looks fine. You can deploy sample worker environment, ssh into it, and compare the files.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. I checked again and the sample code looks identical to the one deployed. Could the issue be in the new version 3.0.1 of the sqs-daemon?Is there a way to use the aws-sqs daemon version 2?

Comment: Which EB environment are you using?

Comment: @Marcin,PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3

Comment: So its current one, there is nothing to update.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?